# .net Mobile Detection Inconsistency

Tags: asp.net, .net

So, i'm trying to detect mobile requests in .net 4.

I discovered the Request.Browser.IsMobile and Request.Browser.MobileDeviceModel. This works great on my windows 7 laptop dev environment. Using my iPad: `IsMobile=true`, and `MobileDeviceModel="IPad"`.

But when I check this on Windows 2008 Server, I'm getting `IsMobile=false`, and `MobileDeviceModel="Unknown"`.

After digging around for a while, I discovered these properties are fueled by xml files in the .net framework folders: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers`
 And then, I noticed that my laptop's Browsers\iphone.xml has ipad info, while my server's same folder and same file does not contain ipad info.

```
<browsers>
    <gateway id="IPhone" parentID="Safari">
      ...
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="IPod" parentID="Safari">
      ...
    </gateway>

    <gateway id="IPad" parentID="Safari">
      <identification>
        <userAgent match="iPad" />
      </identification>

      <capabilities>
        <capability name="isMobileDevice"           value="true" />
        <capability name="mobileDeviceManufacturer" value="Apple" />
        <capability name="mobileDeviceModel"        value="IPad" />
      </capabilities>
    </gateway>
</browsers>
```

My first though is to copy of my browser files over to the server. But I want to make sure it's safe and right to do so. Why would my laptop have these extra devices but not my server? It's the exact same .net version. And, is copying these files over the only thing I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you positive that your laptop doesn't actually have .NET 4.5 installed?  It's installed in the same location in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30313, which is a bit misleading.  If you are using VS2012, then you more than likely have .NET 4.5 installed which could have the extra browser configuration.

In any case, then yes, you should be able to simply move this file over to your server, or upgrade your server to .NET 4.5 if you determine you actually have mismatched versions.

Answer (score 0):

We had to do this on our production servers because we were not yet ready to upgrade to .NET 4.5, but were having browser detection issues that were causing ASP.NET to think IE 10 and 11 did not support JavaScript. The fix was to copy the .browser files from a .NET 4.5 machine to the production web servers and have the .browser files recompiled. Note that the recompile is not free as it will cause IIS to reset, bumping off any users. Also note that we tried this in our lower integration environments before pushing this to production.